# JavaMail not able to display html body

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail

I am having trouble getting the SimpleClient sample app that comes with JavaMail, to work.  Emails with plain text bodies display just fine in the viewer.  But for html bodies it fails to find the appropriate content viewer.  It's the line `Object bean = dh.getBean(ci);` at around line 205 in `MessageViewer.getBodyComponent()`, that results in `bean` getting assigned a null pointer, that causes the problem.

Earlier today I asked for help finding the source for javax.activation, hoping I could figure out the problem.  But unfortunately when I step into that code, it goes to the wrong line in the source file, meaning I can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong!

[I know nothing about Java Beans; this could be my problem.  Please feel free to recommend that I do some learning about this technology :-)    I haven't yet, for the simple reason that I have other things to do with my time.  If, however, it's necessary, then I'll do it :-)  ]

Has anyone else had this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Steps to the wrong line of the code -> you got the code for a different version of Javamail. Match the code to the jar.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the right source of JavaMail, it's the javax.activation source that has the problem.  I have java version 1.6, which apparently includes JAF 1.1, and I have that source, apparently.  This is why I'm stumped on that side of things.  In any case, my question was actually whether anyone else has had problems getting the viewer to show html bodies, and what they did about that.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) has been included in the JDK since JDK 1.6.  You can find the source code in the [OpenJDK repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jaxws/file/d03dd22762db/src/share/jaf_classes) for recent versions.

When JAF was included in the JDK, none of the sample viewers were included.  You can [download the standalone JAF 1.1.1 release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-136939.html), which includes the sample viewers, and include it in your CLASSPATH.

And, just to be really clear, these are sample viewers, perhaps good enough for the [JavaMail sample programs](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), but not good for much else.  In particular, the text viewer displays all text as if it were plain text.  You could get the same effect by changing the simple.mailcap file included with the SimpleClient to use "text/*".

Comment: Thanks for the info and the links, I'll keep plugging away at it :-)